# Multi-website Setting

Tags: websites, .htaccess

To setup multi-website store, I'm following this

https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup

I think I did everything but Edit the .htaccess

As the link said I add those on my .htaccess

SetEnvIf Host www.domain1.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1_com
SetEnvIf Host www.domain1.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www.domain2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2_com
SetEnvIf Host www.domain2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www.domain3.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain3_com
SetEnvIf Host www.domain3.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain3.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain3_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain3.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

I changed domain1 -> mydomain1 , domain2 -> mydomain2 , domain3 -> mydomain3

When I add those on the .htaccess file, I got 404 error: Page not found.

Without those line, I can connect my website

Do I have to add those line? or is it okay without it? or Something worng?

Magento 1.9.01